# Why Apple Mail refuse receiving emails from Amazon SES?

Tags: email, amazon-ses, apple-mail

I got this error from Apple Mail, end of the text is the message, recipient of this message is who was the sender originally:

```
An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
k...@icloud.comReporting-MTA: dns; b224-6.smtp-out.eu-central-1.amazonses.com

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822; k...@icloud.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 [HM07] Message rejected due to local policy. Please visit https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204137
Status: 5.7.1


Feladó: i...@t....com
Tárgy: Program 1
Dátum: 2021. november 26. 21:25:13 CET
Címzett: k...@icloud.com


Jegyedet az alábbi email címen tudod letölteni: 

https://127.0.0.1/getTicketPdf?linkId=034974AF-A4B9-480E-90E9-FEFFB68794C7
```

I checked those best practices, I do not think I violate anything. It is a raw welcome message customer receive about product purchase.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204137